# "Kindly set your character_set_database variable to 'utf8' " says capistrano log when deploying rails app to aws server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to deploy a roughly 10 year old project with ruby 1.9.3 and rails 2.3.18, which had the database upgraded to Mysql 8.0 recently. The error occurs after the following command is ran by capistrano. I'm using capistrano 2.9.0.

`executing "cd path/to/project/releases/20230614043133 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"`

Here is the full log:

```
executing "cd path/to/project/releases/20230614043133 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
    servers: ["X.X.X.X"]
    [X.X.X.X] executing command
 ** [out :: X.X.X.X] path/to/project/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
 ** [out :: X.X.X.X] 
 ** [out :: X.X.X.X] (in path/to/project/releases/20230614043133)
 ** [out :: X.X.X.X] ERROR: MySQL database isn't properly encoded!
 ** [out :: X.X.X.X] Kindly set your character_set_database variable to 'utf8'.
    command finished in 5058ms
```

Here is the database.yml setting,

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: db_development
  username: root
  password: secret

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: db_test
  username: root
  password:

staging:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: db_staging
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  username: root
  password: secret

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: db_production
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  username: root
  password: secret
```

The database had uft8mb3 set by default. I tried changing collation to general ci, unicode 520 but they did not work either. Running `show variables;` within mysql shows that `character_set_database` variable is set to `utf8mb4`. But after selecting the production_database, running `select @@character_set_database` shows `utf8mb3` as the result.

Although I'm not sure if I'm heading the right way, any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have noticed whatever I put in the `value` of encoding inside database.yml, the error message becomes, `Kindly set your character_set_database variable to 'value'.`

Comment: utf8mb4 is preferred, but utf8mb3 (aka utf8) will continue to work.  Collation 520 is antique, but, again, will continue to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by deleting a file named MysqlRequirement.rb in initializer folder that was checking Mysql version and raising error. Not the best solution but it worked. Completed database migration successfully.